# how to select email from yahoo inbox using Selenium IDE

Tags: ide, selenium

i am testing my application with selenium IDE. When a user registered, an activation link will sent to user mail id. now i' m able to login to yahoo mail account and unable to inbox using selenium IDE. Displaying error as " Element id=yui_3_2_0_1_13177110805761411 not found " Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The ID probably changes each time you load the page. You'll have to manually edit the generated HTML test script and put in a more robust locator for the link you are trying to click. Have a read here http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements